# First two terms of the Taylor series of the $n$-th iterated of a holomorpic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $G$ be a region in $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. $G ≠ \emptyset$ is simply connected and open), with $0 \in G$. Let $f: G \to G$ be a holomorphic function that's Taylor series (around $0$) has the shape $z + a_k z^k + \mathcal{O}(\|z^{k+1}\|)$, with $ a_k \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}, k > 1$ (i.e. the Taylor series does not contain any $z^i, 1 < i < k$).

We define the $n$-th iterated $f^{[n]}$ as the composition of $f$ with itself $n$ times, i.e. $f^{[0]} = f$, and $f^{[n]} = f^{[n-1]} \circ f$ for $n ≥ 1$.

**For all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, I now want to determine the first two (additive) terms in the Taylor series of $f^{[n]}$.**

Now for the case $n = 0$, we already know that the first two terms are $z$ and $a_k z^k$, so the solution is trivial. For the other cases, I thought about substituting the Taylor formula in itself, i.e. composing $(z + a_k z^k) $ with itself $n$ times. (The terms of higher order can be ignored I guess, because if we insert any polynomial with degree $≥ 1$ into a $z^{>k}$, then we just get another polynomial with degree $> k$?)

So for the case $n = 1$ for example, would I therefore get by substitution:

$ (z + a_k z^k) + a_k (z + a_k z^k)^k = z + a_k z^k + \sum_{j=0}^k (-1 + z + z^k)^j \pmatrix{k \\ j} $

$=  z - a_k z^k + (-1 + z + z^k)^1\cdot k + (-1 + z + z^k)^2 \cdot \pmatrix{k \\ j} + \text{ higher order terms}  $

Am I on the right track with this; could I therefore get the first 2 (additive) terms by just simplifying that expression? But even if that's possible, I'm having trouble imagining what a general formula for the case $n ≥ 1$ would look like, seeing as the case $n = 1$ already gets so complicated.

Comment: the first term is $z^{n+1}$

Comment: Something seems really off when you turn $a_k(z+a_kz^k)^k$ into a bionomial sum. Also, why not just separate a factor $z$ from $z+a_kz^k = z(1+a_kz^{k-1})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Sorry, first I must change the notation, or my mind will dissolve. Let $f_1 = f, f_2 = f \circ f, \dots $ Note that $f_1(z) = z + a_kz^k + O(z^{k+1}).$ Also note that $(z +O(z^k))^k = z^k + O(z^{k+1}).$ Use this to show $f_2(z) = z + 2 a_kz^k + O(z^{k+1}).$ Hopefully this will be suggestive in finding the first two terms for any $n;$ induction will help.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that seems quite easy, now that I think about it; seems like I messed up in my solution attempt after applying the binomial formula. So if I'm not mistaken, we should inductively get $f_n(z) = z + 2^n a_k z^k + O(z^{k+1})$?

Comment: I get $f_n(z) = z + na_kz^k + O(z^{k+1})$

Comment: Ok I think you're right, I got a little confused with my formulas again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$z+a_kz^k+\cdots$$

$$z+a_kz^k+\cdots a_k(z+a_kz^k+\cdots)^k=z+2a_kz^k+\cdots$$

$$z+a_kz^k+\cdots 2a_k(z+a_kz^k+\cdots)^k=z+3a_kz^k+\cdots$$

$$z+a_kz^k+\cdots 3a_k(z+a_kz^k+\cdots)^k=z+4a_kz^k+\cdots$$

$$\cdots$$

Comment: upvoted: that's basically it.